# Filling in missing calendar dates in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table A with ID, date_yyyymmdd, amount and hours as shown below. Not all calendar dates are populated.

| id | date_yyyymmdd | amount | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 1428.95 | 11 |
| 1 | 23020103 | 1791.29 | 13 |
| 2 | 20230101 | 2516.84 | 15 |
| 2 | 20230105 | 3046.08 | 5 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 7137.92 | 11 |
| 3 | 20230103 | 1104.35 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230104 | 25 | 1 |

I would like to fill in missing calendar dates between two variables start_date and end_date and produce table B as shown below and populate amount and hours as 0s for those dates. In the example below the start date is 20230101 and end date is 20230105. Is there a snowflake calendar function available to fill in the missing dates between two dates?

| id | date_yyyymmdd | amount | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 1428.95 | 11 |
| 1 | 20230102 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20230103 | 1791.29 | 13 |
| 1 | 20230104 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20230105 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230101 | 2516.84 | 15 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230103 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230104 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20230105 | 3046.08 | 5 |
| 3 | 20230101 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 7137.92 | 11 |
| 3 | 20230103 | 1104.35 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230104 | 25 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230105 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the date ranges for each id (excluding existing dates)..then stack missing dates on top of your existing data. There are 4 key steps involved in this. Here's a demo..

**Data**

```
create or replace temporary table t as

with cte (id, dt, amt, hr) as

(select 1,'2023-01-03'::date,100,5 union all
 select 1,'2023-01-05'::date,130,6 union all
 select 2,'2023-01-03'::date,160,1 union all
 select 2,'2023-01-07'::date,100,4)

select * 
from cte;
```

**Code**

```
set (min_dt, range_dt) = (select min(dt), max(dt) - min(dt) from t);

with missing_dates (id, dt) as

(select a.id, $min_dt+b.index -- 2. add row index to generate dates
 from (select distinct id from t) a ,
 lateral flatten(array_generate_range(0,$range_dt+1)) b -- 1. generate as many rows as date range
 except -- 3. exclude dates that already exist
 select id, dt
 from t)

select id, dt, amt, hr
from t
union all --4. stack them up
select id, dt, 0, 0
from missing_dates
order by id, dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

So yet another way todo it, given you noted you "have varaibles" for the start/end time range:

```
set start_date = '2023-01-01'::date;
set end_date = '2023-01-05'::date;
```

then we can use them:

```
with fake_data(id, _date, amount, hours) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2023-01-01'::date, 1428.95, 11),
        (1, '2023-01-03'::date, 1791.29, 13),
        (2, '2023-01-01'::date, 2516.84, 15),
        (2, '2023-01-05'::date, 3046.08, 5),
        (3, '2023-01-02'::date, 7137.92, 11),
        (3, '2023-01-03'::date, 1104.35, 1),
        (3, '2023-01-04'::date, 25, 1)
), date_range as (
    select 
        dateadd('day',
            row_number() over (order by null)-1,
            $start_date -- Put you start date variable here
        ) as _date 
    from table(generator(rowcount=>1000))
    qualify _date <= $end_date -- Put you end date variable here
), dist_ids as (
    select distinct id from fake_data
)
select
    i.id,
    r._date as date_yyyymmdd,
    zeroifnull(d.amount) as amount,
    zeroifnull(d.hours) as hours
from dist_ids as i 
cross join date_range as r
left join fake_data as d
  on i.id = d.id 
      and r._date = d._date
order by 1,2
```

[image]

If you don't have variables already, you can extract them out of that data, like how the others have shown, but in one step like so:

```
with fake_data(id, _date, amount, hours) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2023-01-01'::date, 1428.95, 11),
        (1, '2023-01-03'::date, 1791.29, 13),
        (2, '2023-01-01'::date, 2516.84, 15),
        (2, '2023-01-05'::date, 3046.08, 5),
        (3, '2023-01-02'::date, 7137.92, 11),
        (3, '2023-01-03'::date, 1104.35, 1),
        (3, '2023-01-04'::date, 25, 1)
), min_max as (
    select  min(_date) as min_d
        ,max(_date) - min_d + 1 as days
    from fake_data
), date_range as (
    select 
        dateadd('day', r.value, m.min_d ) as _date 
    from min_max as m,
     lateral flatten(array_generate_range(0, m.days)) as r
), dist_ids as (
    select distinct id from fake_data
)
select
    i.id,
    r._date as date_yyyymmdd,
    zeroifnull(d.amount) as amount,
    zeroifnull(d.hours) as hours
from dist_ids as i 
cross join date_range as r
left join fake_data as d
  on i.id = d.id 
      and r._date = d._date
order by 1,2
```

giving again, the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer from [@Radagast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9947159/radagast), but this one could be wrapped in a view. Table t1 would be replaced with your actual Snowflake table:

```sql
with t0 as (
    select
        '2023-01-01' as start_date,
        '2023-01-05' as end_date,
        datediff("days", start_date, end_date) + 1 range
) ,t1(id, date_yyyymmdd, amount, hours) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2023-01-01'::date, 1428.95, 11),
    (1, '2023-01-03'::date, 1791.29, 13),
    (2, '2023-01-01'::date, 2516.84, 15),
    (2, '2023-01-05'::date, 3046.08, 5),
    (3, '2023-01-02'::date, 7137.92, 11),
    (3, '2023-01-03'::date, 1104.35, 1),
    (3, '2023-01-04'::date, 25, 1)
), t2 as (
    select
        distinct(t1.id),
        dateadd("days", a.index, t0.start_date) date_yyyymmdd
    from t0, t1,
    lateral flatten(array_generate_range(0, t0.range)) a
)
select
    t2.id,
    t2.date_yyyymmdd,
    coalesce(t1.amount, 0) amount,
    coalesce(t1.hours, 0) hours
from t2 left join t1
on t2.id = t1.id
and t2.date_yyyymmdd = t1.date_yyyymmdd
order by 1,2
```